# Почему числа игнорируются функцией МИН (МАКС)

Tags: excel, office, excel-формулы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно посчитать минимальное, максимальное и среднезнач. в столбике "Red" - выдает ошибку, а для мин и макс  - "0", в чем может быть проблема? Числа в правильном формате, каждое число было вырезано с колонки RGB при помощи функций пример для колонки "RED" =ЛЕВБ(C5;ПОИСК(",";C5)-1) возможно она как-тo мешает?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы невнимательны. В Вашей прошлой теме я специально написал о переводе текстовых записей чисел в число. И в формулах там есть двойное отрицание

Comment: спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функции *ЛЕВБ, ПРАВСИМВ, ПСТР* и прочие **текстовые** функции (функции для работы с текстовыми данными) извлекают из текста числа в текстовом формате, которые многими функциями (*МИН, МАКС, СУММ...*) так и воспринимаются (как текст) и игнорируют такие значения при расчетах.

Поэтому при получении чисел из текста их нужно преобразовывать в числовой формат. Это можно сделать с помощью математических операций или оператора **--** (двойное отрицание):

```
=ЛЕВБ(A2;5)*1

=ПРАВСИМВ(A2;3)+0

=--ПСТР(A2;4;5)
```

Если же данные на листе по каким-то причинам преобразовать не получается, это можно сделать в формуле:

```
=МАКС(--A2:A25)
```

Но, т.к. теперь в функции производится дополнительная обработка массива, формула должна вводиться с как формула массива: завершать редактирование формулы нужно тремя клавишами - *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*. при этом формула должна обрамиться фигурными скобками.